# Press F10 to exit debugging in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio

As we all know, when using Visual Studio to debug C# code, pressing F10 can debug single-step execution. But during recent debugging the program breaks debugging whenever I hold down F10.

I tried to check the key settings of this function in the settings of Visual Studio, but I didn't find any difference.

[image]

Has anyone encountered similar problems? How to solve it in the end?

Comment: Show us the contents of VS's `Debug > Output` window when this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you can refer to the following steps first:

1.Tools=>Environmrnt=>Keyboard

Select the corresponding programming language in "Apply the following additional keyboard mapping scheme" (for example, if I use C#, choose Visual C# 2005), and then click Reset.

[image]

2. Repair Visual Studio using Visual Studio Installer
3. Reinstall Visual Studio

If the above operation does not work, please tell me what operation did you perform using Visual Studio to cause issue?

Comment: It turns out that the end of the universe is reinstallation